# Suppose $y(x)$ is continuous and $y'(x)=0$ has uncountable many solutions but $y(x)$ is not constant on any interval. Is this possible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $y(x)$ is continuous and $y'(x)=0$ has uncountable many solutions but $y(x)$ is not constant on any interval. Is this possible?

Comment: Wouldn't taking something like $y'(x) = d$ where $d$ is distance between $x$ and the closest point of Cantor set do the trick? (Just an idea, didn't make rigorous proof yet).

Comment: What if require it to be $C^k$, or $C^\infty$?

Comment: I would usually recommend *Counterexamples in Analysis* for this kind of question but it isn't in there.  My copy is getting updated...

Comment: Related: [Find a Continuous Function with Cantor Set Level Sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752178/find-a-continuous-function-with-cantor-set-level-sets)

Answer (score 3):

Take a Cantor set $C\subseteq [0,1]$ and let $d(x)$ be the distance function from $x$ to $C$.  Then $(d(x))^2$ is differentiable with derivative vanishing at all points of $C$ hence uncountably many.

Comment: By $d^2(x)$ do you mean $d(d(x))$ or $(d(x))^2$?  My brain doesn't like $d(d(x))$.

Comment: Good point.  I like differentials including second-order ones, but in this case they are irrelevant :-) @Yakk

Comment: $(d(x))^2$ isn't differentiable at the midpoints of the intervals making up the complement of $C$. You need to modify the function around these points.

Comment: The OP did not require the function to be differentiable everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is true. A classic example of such an odd function is the Cantor function. It is defined like this: for $x$ in $[0,1]$

1.Express x in base 3.

2.If x contains a 1, replace every digit after the first 1 by 0.

3.Replace all 2s with 1s.

4.Interpret the result as a binary number. The result is c(x).

This function has derivative $0$ *almost everywhere* (i.e. the places where it doesn't have $0$ derivative has measure $0$) and yet somehow manages to increase in value from $0$ at $x=0$ to $1$ at $x=1$.

There is plenty written about the Cantor function. Perhaps wikipedia would be the best starting place: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: Cantor function is constant on $({1 \over 3},{2 \over 3})$, isn't it?

Comment: oh yes I didn't see the OP's last condition was a bit different from usual :( perhaps then this page could be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250628/constructing-a-strictly-increasing-function-with-zero-derivatives