# Nowhere dense definition. How to see the equivalence?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, definition

One of the answers given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237159/understanding-the-definition-of-nowhere-dense-sets-in-abbotts-understanding-ana) wrote

> 2. A subset $Y \subseteq X$ is called to be *somewhere dense* if there exists a non-empty open set $U\subseteq X$ such that we have $\overline{Y\cap U}=\overline{U}.$ As one can see, here by **some where** we actually mean an open set; This attitude seems quite natural since the open sets constitute actually the most fundamental part of a topological space.
> 3. A subset $Y \subseteq X$ is called *nowhere dense*, if it is not the case that it is somewhere dense. It is easy to see that $Y$ is nowhere dense if and only if $\overline{Y}$ does not contain a non-empty open set; the latter is equivalent to the standard definition of a nowhere dense set.

How does one go from (2) to (3)? Shouldn't the case of "not somewhere dense" be

For every open set $U\subset X$ we don't have $\overline{Y \cap U} = \overline{U}?$ Or since $\overline{Y \cap U} \subset \overline{Y} \cap \overline{U} \subset \overline{U}$, this is equivalent to never having $\overline{U} \subset \overline{Y\cap U}?$

Comment: Another equivalent formulation: for every non-empty open set $U$ there is a non-empty open subset $V$ of $U$ that misses $Y$. So $Y$ could be called "very avoidable" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is nowhere dense in the sense derived from 2., so not anywhere dense,  consider $\overline{Y}$: if this contained a non-empty open set $U \subseteq \overline{Y}$, then $$\overline{U \cap Y} = \overline{U \cap \overline{Y}}\tag{1}$$ (as $U$ is open, this holds for any subset $Y$), and the latter equals $\overline{U}$, and so $Y$ would be dense in $U$, contradicting its definition.

If however we know that $Y$ is somewhere dense, say in $U$, we have

$$U \subseteq \overline{U}= \overline{U \cap Y} \subseteq \overline{Y}$$

and $\overline{Y}$ has non-empty interior. So the definitions are equivalent.

Comment: So first off, I guess this does boil down to the statement $$\overline{U} \subset \overline{Y \cap U} \iff U \subset \overline{Y}$$

Comment: Next, could you elaborate how $U$ being open implies $$\overline{U \cap Y} = \overline{U \cap \overline{Y}}$$

Comment: I wrote something different. That is first $U \subset \overline{Y} \implies \overline{U} \subset \overline{Y}$. So $$x \in \overline{U} \iff B(x) \cap U \neq \emptyset$$ and $B(x) \cap Y \neq \emptyset$ so $B(x) \cap Y \cap U \neq \emptyset$ is the required condition?

Comment: @Hawk That's a standard fact: the left to right inclusion is trivial, and if $x$ is in the right hand side, let $V$ be any open neighbourhood of it: it intersects $U \cap Y$ because $V \cap U$ is also non-empty and must intersect $Y$. etc.

Comment: I just looked at your edited comment. That's more or less what I wrote above yours right?

Comment: From right to left that is, because as you said  one inclusion is trivial

Comment: @Hawk almost, yes. Mine is clearer though, IMO.

Comment: Let me flesh this out. Because $x \in U \subset \overline{Y}$  the condition of being in both closures $\overline{U}$ and $\overline{Y}$ means any neighborhood $B(x)$ must intersect both $U$ and $Y$, but that's exactly means being in $\overline{Y \cap U}$

Comment: Also just a small correction, you mean to write "nowhere dense derived from (3)" right? (2) is somewhere dense

Comment: @Hawk it’s the negation of somewhere dense, so derived from 2. And 3 also mentions the alternative so is ambiguous. In your sketch of proof you don’t make it clear where you use openness of $U$, which is essential.